# how can i track how many times a user as logged in and store it in data base php code

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a **session** but i want to track how manytimes someone has logged in and logged out and store it in data base so that admin can view it.

i tired googling many website but did nt get sloution so help me out

Comment: `"i tired googling many website but did nt get sloution so help me out"`. No copy paste solutions here. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.. one way is ..

Create a field like login_num

Whenever the user logs in, Increment the field log_in everytime.

after the user logs in, use a query something like below

```
update logintable set login_num=login_num+1 where username='john'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert `+1` every time when user `Logged in`.

### **Pseudo Code:**

**First Time:**
If user successfully logged in insert `+1` in Database using `Insert statement.`

**Second Time:** If user logged in again, fetch the current status of the `Logged in Count` from your databse like `3` and add `+1` to it.

Comment: I would record more data not just how many times he logged in, for instance, login timestamp

Comment: then, make another table with user_id, timestamp, etc. Then, make count of rows

Comment: thanks but i am not able to store time properly and how about logout time and can we store how long user was on that page

Answer (score 2):

Just use a simple method:

Just create a database in this format: (**login**)

```
---------------------------------------
id (AI)  | username | time  | date 
--------------------------------------
1    | sample  | 12.23 | 2014-06-2014
```

and just use this code in PHP and mysql (Put this code into where you trying to login)

```
mysql_query("insert into login ( username, time , date ) values ( '(username)', '".date("h:i")."' , '".date("Y-m-d")."' ) ");
```

Then you can the fetch values anytime where need including your admin pannel...

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from login");

while ($list - mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $list["username"]. " - ".$list["date"]."-".$list["time"]. '<br>';
}
```